# ActiveMQ 5.9 - BLOCKED threads on broker due to lock not released

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm using ActiveMQ 5.9 with Camel 2.10.3, and under load (during a performance test) I'm experiencing some problems, it seems that the broker is stuck trying to close a connection, and I can't understand the reason.

The configuration of the JMS system is the following: there are two broker (configured in failover mode) and many client nodes that acts both as consumer both as producer of some queues (let's take one for example: 'customer_update queue'.

I'm using PooledConnectionFactory with default configuration, 'CACHE_CONSUMER' cache level and 10 max concurrent consumer per each client node.

Broker configuration is the following: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600

Here's the thread holding lock on the broker, and never releasing it:

```
"ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///10.128.43.206:38694@61616" #5774 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f2a4424e800 nid=0
xaba4 waiting on condition [0x00007f29fe397000]
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000004fd008fb0> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.
java:1037)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1328)
at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:277)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.stop(TransportConnection.java:983)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processAddConnection(TransportConnection.java:699)
        - locked <0x000000050401eed0> (a java.lang.Object)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedTransportConnection.processAddConnection(ManagedTransportConnection.java:79)
at org.apache.activemq.command.ConnectionInfo.visit(ConnectionInfo.java:139)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:292)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:149)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:113)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:270)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:214)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have more than 500 other threads on the broker that look like this:

```
"ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///10.128.43.206:52074@61616" #2962 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f2a440c9000 nid=0xa01f waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f29fc768000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processAddConnection(TransportConnection.java:696)
        - waiting to lock <0x000000050401eed0> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedTransportConnection.processAddConnection(ManagedTransportConnection.java:79)
        at org.apache.activemq.command.ConnectionInfo.visit(ConnectionInfo.java:139)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:292)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:149)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:113)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:270)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:214)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

First error I see on the broker is this one:

```
2018-05-16 16:36:59,336 [org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport:856] 
WARN  - Transport Connection to: tcp://10.128.43.206:48747 failed: java.io.EOFException
```

On the client node that is referenced in the broker (10.128.43.206), I see this logs, it seems that the node is trying to reconnect, but right after it's disconnected again, and this happens again and again.

```
2018-05-16 16:36:59,322 [org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport:856] WARN  - Transport (tcp://10.128.43.169:61616) failed, reason:  java.io.IOException, attempting to automatically reconnect
2018-05-16 16:36:59,322 [org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport:856] WARN  - Transport (tcp://10.128.43.169:61616) failed, reason:  java.io.IOException, attempting to automatically reconnect
2018-05-16 16:36:59,375 [org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport:856] INFO  - Successfully reconnected to tcp://10.128.43.169:61616
2018-05-16 16:36:59,375 [org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport:856] INFO  - Successfully reconnected to tcp://10.128.43.169:61616
2018-05-16 16:36:59,375 [org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext:856] INFO  - commit failed for transaction TX:ID:52374-1526300283331-1:1:898
javax.jms.TransactionRolledBackException: Transaction completion in doubt due to failover. Forcing rollback of TX:ID:52374-1526300283331-1:1:898
        at org.apache.activemq.state.ConnectionStateTracker.restoreTransactions(ConnectionStateTracker.java:231)
        at org.apache.activemq.state.ConnectionStateTracker.restore(ConnectionStateTracker.java:169)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport.restoreTransport(FailoverTransport.java:827)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport.doReconnect(FailoverTransport.java:1005)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport$2.iterate(FailoverTransport.java:136)
        at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:129)
        at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:47)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-05-16 16:37:00,091 [org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport:856] INFO  - Successfully reconnected to tcp://10.128.43.169:61616
2018-05-16 16:37:00,091 [org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport:856] INFO  - Successfully reconnected to tcp://10.128.43.169:61616
2018-05-16 16:37:00,112 [org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport:856] WARN  - Transport (tcp://10.128.43.169:61616) failed, reason:  java.io.IOException, attempting to automatically reconnect
```

At the end, broker reach maxConnections available (1000), and needs to be restarted.

Could it be due to the fact that one client node is acting both as a consumer and a producer, using same connection pool, generating some kind of deadlock?

Do you have some suggestions?

Thanks

Giulio

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most probably I was affected by this issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5090

Updating to ActiveMQ 5.10.0 and Camel 2.13.1 solved the issue (system is much more stable, even during performance tests).

Thanks
Giulio

Comment: still coming in 5.15.13

Comment: Hi @shivam, I'm sorry for that. Are you experiencing the same issue as I was?